# Window is not displayed when running application

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I have a problem with a simple TCP/IP chat application in Visual Basic. When I run the server application its window is not shown and I don't know why. However, the server is working properly. The server code is shown below.

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        Dim server As TcpListener
        server = Nothing

        ' Set the TcpListener on port 13000. 
        Dim port As Int32 = 13000
        Dim localAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")

        server = New TcpListener(localAddr, port)

        ' Start listening for client requests.
        server.Start()

        ' Buffer for reading data 
        Dim bytes(1024) As Byte
        Dim data As String = Nothing

        ' Enter the listening loop. 
        While True
            TextBox1.Text = "Waiting For connections"

            ' Perform a blocking call to accept requests. 
            ' You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here. 
            Dim client As TcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient()

            TextBox2.Text = "Connected!"

            data = Nothing

            ' Get a stream object for reading and writing 
            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

            Dim i As Int32

            ' Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

            While (i > 0)
                ' Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)
                TextBox3.Text = "Received:" & data

                ' Process the data sent by the client.
                data = data.ToUpper()
                Dim msg As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

                ' Send back a response.
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length)
                TextBox4.Text = "Sent:" & data

                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

            End While

            ' Shutdown and end connection
            client.Close()
        End While

        server.Stop()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running your server on the UI thread in `Form.Load`.  Until `Form.Load` completes, your form will not be visible.  You should probably run your server logic on a new thread.  The problem you will run into then is that you can't update the UI (e.g. `TextBox1.Text = "Waiting For connections"`) from a non-UI thread, so you will need to use `Invoke` for those.  e.g. (totally untested, just to give you an idea what to try):

```
Imports System.Threading

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t = New Thread(AddressOf RunServer)
    t.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub RunServer()
    ' Move your code from Form1_Load here, but when updating the UI,
    ' use something like:
    Me.Invoke(Sub() TextBox1.Text = "Waiting For connections")
End Sub
```